# Save product id while place order. Magento

Tags: magento, checkout

I have to save product id and customer id after customer place order. Where and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` event or the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` if you use the default One Page Checkout checkout. The former is called when an order is created and saved, the latter when a order is succesfully placed.

You can find a tutorial about how to use events here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I think place_order is a more accurate observer in this context as the order may get save every time the status changes so the code will be called more often and the customer and product will keep on stacking unless there is a check.

Comment: sales_order_place_after is the event I am talking about... but I think it is more payment event than order.